# Configure CloudWatch log to a running instance programmatically

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-java-sdk, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I just tried to configure the cloudwatch to a running ec2-instance(windows) , manually using the steps given in aws-cloudwatch-documentation and ended successfully. the cloud watch log groups are created and the logs are being logged correctly. 
   Now my query is, Is there any way to do the cloud watch configuration through code(programattically using JAVA) or script or powershell, ???
 If yes, kindly share some samples

Comment: I am not too familar with window, but in linux I would probably create a base image from the instance with the cloudwatch already setup and use that base image for launching new ec2-instance. 
Or if the script is not too complicated, I would put it in the UserData

Comment: @Gigapalmer thanks for the reply. but my doubt is how to setup cloudwatch programatically(either using a script like powershell or using aws-sdk)in an instance which is already launched(or created) and running. and i need a sample for the same.